# $\text{Aut}(P) \cong \text{GL}(\Bbb{F}_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The textbook claims that a elementary abelian $p$-group $P$ corresponds to a vector space and $\text{Aut}(P) \cong \text{GL}(\Bbb{F}_p)$. I don't understand why there is such equivalent relationship between invertible matrix and automorphism. How do you know each matrix is an automorphism and each automorphism is a matrix?

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume $P$ is finite, but the results hold in a suitable sense
when $P$ is infinite too.

The elementary Abelian group $P$ may be identified with a vector space
$\newcommand{\F}{\Bbb F_p}(\F)^n$ over $\F$, that is the space of $n$-tuples $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with the $x_i\in\F$. Then each group homomorphism $P\to P$ is the same as an $\F$-linear map $(\F)^n\to(\F)^n$
and is represented by a matrix. This matrix is invertible iff the
homomorphism is an automorphism. Therefore $\text{Aut}(P)$
corresponds to $\text{GL}_n(\F)$, the group of non-singular $n$-by-$n$
matrices over $\F$.